# SQL Server Analysis Services still needed if using Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi

I have a project that requires using SQL Server Analysis Services, but we've also started looking at PowerBI.

I'm not entirely clear on how PowerBI functions, and where the computations/data storage takes place. If we use PowerBI for generating the analytics, is there still a benefit to having an Analysis Services layer?

Comment: Who built your existing SSAS model? Are they going to be happy to move all that logic into a Power BI model? Do they think Power BI desktop is a sufficiently advanced modelling environment? Where does your SSAS model data come from? In short, data modelling (joins, calcs, columns, formatting, rollups etc.) can be done in Power BI but longer term it's better to store a central data model in a less adhoc fashion, i.e. in SSAS

Comment: A range of ways of doing things: Power BI can be used atop of an SSAS model (and this then restricts the additional power BI modelling you can do in addition, so plan on using the SSAS model raw). A Power BI model is a mini SSAS Tabular instance: you could start here, then grow up to an Analysis Services model (whether on premises or in the cloud). A lot depends on the size of the model, complexity, whether to be used by other end user applications, etc, and whether you are using Power BI on the desktop only or also in the online service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Use Analysis Services or Not?**

It depends. If you already have an Analysis Services (SSAS) model, as Caio mentions, then I wouldn't get rid of it. Power BI works very well with Analysis Services and Analysis Services is going to offer a lot of enterprise-grade options that Power BI isn't going to improve upon (such as the ability to handle millions of new rows each day).

However, if you don't have an Analysis Services model already, SSAS isn't a prerequisite for using Power BI. As Mike mentions, Power BI is fully featured by itself and can easily handle most needs (importing data, modeling the data, and then visualizing the data).

To answer your question about computation and storage, Power BI has a number of layers:

1. An ETL layer (M). This is how data is brought into your model.
2. A modeling layer (DAX). This is where the data is stored, and where calculations run.
3. A visualization layer.

When you use Power BI with Analysis Services in Direct Query mode, then the ETL & data modeling side of things are handled by SSAS. All computation & data storage happens in Analysis Services and Power BI becomes a visualization layer only, sending queries to Analysis Services as needed for your reports.

When you don't have Analysis Services (and are using Data Import mode), then the data is stored in Power BI and all the computations run inside Power BI too.

**Pros & Cons of Each Option**

The advantage of using Power BI without SSAS is ***speed of delivery***. Everything is handled in one file by one person. If you need to change your data model to make a report work, you can do that within Power BI. When you have a SSAS model, making changes to your data model can be cumbersome (partly because you have to use another tool and partly because any changes will affect all users).

The advantage of using Power BI with SSAS is ***scalability***. Configured correctly, a single Analysis Services model can grow to handle hundreds of gigabytes, hundreds of reports, and hundreds of users with no issue. Analysis Services offers a level of enterprise robustness that goes beyond what you'd want a Power BI file to handle.

That said, introducing Analysis Services brings a number of disadvantages: most importantly, licensing & maintaining a SQL Server & keeping that server up-to-date. Power BI Desktop is updated monthly and is a quick download to get the latest & greatest DAX features. Using SSAS means you have to wait for new releases of SQL Server that include the same DAX features, then test & install them.

**Conclusion**

If you're not dealing with vast amounts of data (e.g. millions of new rows each month), one way to know if you need the enterprise-grade features of Analysis Services would be to think about the reports needed at the end of the project. If there's a dozen or less reports and you plan to build them all yourself, then Power BI alone offers a lot of advantages. If, on the other hand, there's a whole department of report writers waiting for you to build a data model, then Analysis Services is the way to go.

---

**Sidenote**

What's more important than Analysis Services vs. Power BI for ETL/modeling is getting your data model right. A poor data model will be slow using either tool. A well-designed data model will be fast using either option. Make sure to spend plenty of time understanding best practices when it comes to modeling your data. "Analyzing Data with Power BI and Power Pivot for Excel" by Alberto Ferrari & Marco Russo is well worth picking up if you're new to data modeling & BI in general. (Not saying you are.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely need to keep your Analysis Services layer (and other data sources you might have). Power BI is a reporting tool and should receive data pre-aggregated as much as possible, enough to be able to plot charts, display tables, apply filters, etc. The heavy lifting is done at the data source level.

There are a number of limitations in Power BI, and you should plan for that.

For instance:

> **There is a 1 million row limit for returning data when using
>   DirectQuery**. This does not affect aggregations or calculations used to
>   create the dataset returned using DirectQuery, only the rows returned.
>   For example, you can aggregate 10 million rows with your query that
>   runs on the data source, and accurately return the results of that
>   aggregation to Power BI using DirectQuery as long as the data returned
>   to Power BI is less than 1 million rows. If more than 1 million rows
>   would be returned from DirectQuery, Power BI returns an error.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont need a separate Analysis Services instance - only for very large models. In the default Import mode you are only limited by a model size of 1GB for Free or Pro accounts. Due to effective data compression this can be many millions of rows. A rough basis for estimation would be 50m rows in 1GB. Performance is excellent.

Power BI actually spins up an internal Analysis Services instance when a model is in use, which handles all the analytic/calculation requirements. When using Power BI Desktop this runs on your PC (you can watch it in the Task Manager). When using the web service it runs in the cloud. With Power BI Report Server it runs on an on-premise server. You can connect to any of those using Excel Pivot Tables etc, just as you would with regular Analysis Services.